# Mapping with pairs

Tags: haskell

I'm really new to Haskell and I'm stuck on trying to map the first item of each pair in a list.

Obviously this works:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f xs = [f x | x <- xs]
```

But how do I get it to work for

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [(a, Int)] -> [b]
```

I just want it to ignore the Int values for now and apply f to a like it does in the first example. I've been trying for ages now so thanks for any help.

Comment: If an answer helped you, please click the tick mark next to it to mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, assuming you don't want to use the build-in function `map`, starting from this:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f xs = [f x | x <- xs]
```

To accept a list of type `[(a, Int)]` and use just the `a`, you can pattern match the tuple:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [(a, Int)] -> [b]
map f xs = [f x | (x, y) <- xs]
```

If you want to keep the `Int`, you can put it back together afterwards:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [(a, Int)] -> [(b, Int)]
map f xs = [(f x, y) | (x, y) <- xs]
```

But all of this is a bit redundant. You can do the same by changing the argument to the original, generic `map`:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f xs = [f x | x <- xs]

mapFst :: (a -> b) -> [(a, Int)] -> [b]
mapFst f xs = map (f . fst) xs

mapOnFirst :: (a -> b) -> [(a, Int)] -> [(b, Int)]
mapOnFirst f xs = map (\(x,y) -> (f x, y)) xs
```

For the third version, the standard library's module `Control.Arrow` gives you a function called `first` that can be used to get the same effect:

```
mapOnFirst :: (a -> b) -> [(a, Int)] -> [(b, Int)]
mapOnFirst f xs = map (first f) xs
```

Neat, huh?

Comment: +1, but the question has `(a -> b) -> [(a, Int)] -> [b]`, not `(a -> b) -> [(a, Int)] -> [(b, Int)]`.

Comment: @ehird: Yeah, but the question mentioned ignoring the `Int` values "for now" so it seemed useful to include both versions while I was at it.

Comment: Ah, didn't realise you had `mapFst` in there.

Comment: just wondering what the \ is used for in the first mapOnFirst example?

Comment: @user1131194: Oh, sorry--it's a lambda expression, it creates an anonymous function. So `\(x,y) -> (y, x)` would be equivalent to  `swap (x, y) = (y, x)`, except you don't have to declare it.

Answer (score 2):

```
mapfst :: (a -> b) -> [(a, c)] -> [b]
mapfst f = map f . map fst
```

Read from right to left: the `map fst` extracts all the first values, then the `map f` applies the function to each first value.

Comment: +1, but `map (f . fst)` is better (especially if you want to examine the Int in future).

Comment: `mapFirst :: (a -> b) -> [(a,c)] -> [(b,c)]; mapFirst = map . first`, inspired by [semantic editor combinators](http://conal.net/blog/posts/semantic-editor-combinators), is a similar function to think about.

Comment: @ehird - how is that better, and what does that have to do with examining the `snd` part of the tuple? I thought `map foo . map bar` could always be optimized into `map (foo . bar)` with no performance difference except 1 pass instead of 2 over the list.

Comment: @DanBurton: It's not about optimisation; if you have `map (f . fst)`, you only have to change one localised place in the source code (`f . fst`), not two (`f` and `. map fst`); it isolates the discarding of the second element so the behaviour can be more easily changed later (per the question: "I just want it to ignore the Int values *for now*", emphasis mine). But yes, I think GHC's `RULE` pragmas should always optimise `map f . map g` into `map (f . g)`.

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward extension of what you already have, using list comprehensions:

```
map' :: (a -> b) -> [(a, Int)] -> [b]
map' f xs = [ f x | (x, _) <- xs ]
```